# How to setup javascript threejs library with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, three.js, browserify

My problem is that I had been working with threejs 3 years ago, and I remember that when you had to include the library you had to use:

```html
<script src="cdn-router-threejs"></script>
```

But now in the documentation they use another way to import the library: **npm**

Acording to that I follow all steps:

1. Install node.js (`node -v` response `v12.16.3`)
2. Create a folder for my project (threejs-example)
3. Inside the folder I execute `npm init` to setup my project in my folder. By default *package-json* file my main script is called *index.js*.
4. Execute `npm install --save three` to download the libraries
5. In *index.js* insert the lines:

   ```js
   import * as THREE from 'three';
   const scene = new THREE.Scene();
   ```
6. I don't know how to continue from this point. I have tried:

   - a) I write in my *index.html*

     ```html
     <script type="module" defer src="index.js"></script>
     ```

     But that option doesn't work.
   - b) I have tried to create a bundle with the library `webpack` and `browserify` but I wasn't successful.

   In the case of `browserify` I type:

   ```
   npm install -g browserify
   browserify index.js -o bundle.js
   ```

   And I get the following error:

   [image: error when i type browserify index.js -o bundle.js]

   In the case of `webpack`: Dont really know how to do it.

Any advise would be appreciated. Thank you in advanced

Comment: There is a simple starter project that shows how you can use `three.js`'s ES6 modules with rollup: https://github.com/Mugen87/three-jsm

Comment: ohh, thank you!. I have been looking for a lot!! but not successful. I will try and I will let you know

Comment: but rollup is another module bundler, and I am getting really frustrated with so many diferent modules. dont know which one to use or if there is a kind of standard. So I am guessing that when you make a project no matter which one, you have to follow a folder structure, haven't you?

Comment: Well, you can arrange directories as you like. In general, properly working with a bundler is a basic JS skill and unrelated to `three.js`. I can only recommend to take your time and study how the above project works. It so much better to work with modules and bundle your code than working with global scripts.

Comment: Thank you Mugen87. It is working. I dont really understand the way it works but I guess is a matter of investigation. ;)